# Providing configuration for a Class accepting multiple generic classes

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns

I've been wrangling with this design and I think I'm trying to force a solution to a problem I'm creating with a poor design choice, but I'd like to get some external input.

Essentially, I have several concrete implementations of a class producing data, and a class consuming data, the data itself can be of various types. I would like a user to be able to choose an arbitrary producer of data, and list the corresponding compatible consumers (which accept the type of data provided by the producer). The data itself could be something as simple as an `int` or `string` every production cycle.

I've tried to flesh the simplified situation below. My issue comes when I actually try and think about instantiating an engine with a concrete consumer/producer. I've commented the below example, suggesting ideas I'm exploring.

As I'm typing this, it seems that the sensible solution would be to make all my producable/consumable types something like `IData`, a simple wrapper around the type which will be produced/consumed, but this seems like overkill, in that I'll likely be dealing with primitive types.

I'm sure there is a really simple solution, I might have been staring at it for too long.

Edit: There is no real restriction or commonality on the types of data that can be produced/consumed, I only want to be able to feed the result from one into the other to be dealt with. Essentially an IProducer and IConsumer can be considered compatible if they share the same type for `T`.

Simplified example:

```
void Main()
{
    // Populated form concrete implementations in assembly.
    var producers = new List<IProducer>();
    var consumers = new List<IConsumer>();

    var engine = new Engine();

    // I'd like to allow the user to choose producer/consumer combinations.
    //engine.Configure();   

    engine.StartWork();
}

public class Engine
{
    public void Configure(IProducer producer, IConsumer consumer)   
    {   
        // Wire up Producer/Consumer, if types are compatible.
        // Simplified chain...
        // consumer.ConsumeSomething(producer.MakeSomething());
    }

    // Do this instead ?
    // Where is configure called from, does it know the types?
    // public void Configure<T>(IProducer<T> producer, IConsumer<T> consumer) {}

    public void StartWork() {}
}

// Instantiate an engine for all concrete producer/consumer types and present the user with a list of engines?
//public class Engine<T> {}

public interface IProducer<T> : IProducer
{
    T MakeSomething();
}

public interface IProducer
{
    // Non Generic producer methods/properties
}

public interface IConsumer<T> : IConsumer
{
    // Some Side effect, or return result.
    void ConsumeSomething(T input);
    //bool ConsumeSomething(T input);
}

public interface IConsumer
{
    // Non Generic consumer methods/properties.
}
```

Comment: Requiring producers/consumers to deal with an `IData` interface might be appropriate, or it might not. It depends a lot on whether your data is expected to itself have some common behaviors, or will simply be used as completely general-purpose types. If the latter, then your producers and consumers should probably be generic, with you matching them based on the generic type parameter. You haven't provided enough specifics here, so there are far too many possible answers for this to be a good Stack Overflow question at the moment. Please narrow it so a reasonable, useful answer can be provided.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. The data will be completely general purpose, no common behaviour required. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: _"The data will be completely general purpose"_ -- then you should just make the producer and consumer types generic (e.g. generic interfaces, as you've shown above). In whatever plug-in architecture you wind up implementing/using, you'll use the generic type parameter to select the candidate consumers for a given producer. If a producer can only handle one type, then a generic producer as you've shown will work; otherwise, you'll have to have an API (e.g. producer factory or something) that gives you a selection of specific producers and/or types that can be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a generic version is fine, however I would not defined an `IData`. Neither would I create something like `IProducer<int>` as that doesn't tell anything about the actual data.

My first design guideline would be to always create meaningful classes for every type of data that can be produced. So instead of `int` as data you would have `WindSpeed`, `Temperature` etc.

If you further analyze the need of data classification you would also see that for instance `WindSpeed` can mean different things in different scenarios. I.e. someone wanting to get the ground wind speed would fell off the chair if they got the wind speed from a wind tunnel, right?

Thus analyze one time again if it's enough to just pick a data type for a consumer. It might be relevant to know which producer the data came from.

Other than that you can use reflection to discover all producers.

Comment: Thanks, this was always a slightly ugly question on my part; your words have caused me to re-evaluate the constraints I'm placing on my data type and the model I'm using. Whilst I'm happy to just use any data type internally, I'm mentally creating a connection that I should be defining statically. I probably agree with the close votes on the this question, I'm currently leaving it answered as the conversation has been helpful.